# Convert characters to asterisks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function that will convert all charactewrs after the first word into asterisks,

Say I have MYFIRSTWORD MYSECONDWORD, id want it to convert to asterisks on Keyup, but only for the second word, rendering it as so...

MYFIRSTWORD *********

I've been using the following only it converts each and every letter, is this possible?

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\s]/g, "*"));
```

Comment: `this.value = this.value.replace( ... );` No need for jQuery here.

Comment: Are you saying that "TEST1 TEST2 TEST3" would become "TEST1 ***** *****"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about doing it with a single regex, but you can do this:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var i = this.value.indexOf(" ");
    if (i > -1) {
        this.value = this.value.substr(0, i) 
                   + this.value.substr(i).replace(/[\S]/g, "*");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fc7ru/

Comment: @linuscl - my answer included a demo fiddle that still works fine for me (Even on my phone). Are you saying the fiddle doesn't work for you, or that you used the code in your own project and it didn't work there? (If the latter, have you included jQuery? Have you wrapped the code in a document ready handler? Which browser?)

Comment: The jsfiddle is not working in my browser. Look at the screenshot: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11055314/Bildschirmfotovom2015-11-19163148.png.html

Comment: I misunderstood the questioner, excuse me. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onkeyup='$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\s]/g, "*"));' />
```

Check in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7YEr/)

Comment: Please post your code here; the point of Stackoverflow is to be self-contained, rather than relying on external sites to remain functional/accessible. Use JS Fiddle for *demos*, not as a *repository*.

Comment: I'm wondering who upvoted this. This is just the copy of the OP's code, it does not work. Flagged as not an answer.

Comment: You don't have to show the code working here, you should show *code that works* in your *answer*, and link to a demo elsewhere that shows the code actually working.

Answer (score -1):

you should try this code

```
var array =  $(this).val().split(" ");
var newValue = "";
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  if ( i==0){
    newValue = array[i];
    continue;
  } else{
    newValue+= array[i].replace(/[^\s]/g, "*");
  }
}

$(this).val(newValue);
```

Comment: If you don't mind some suggestions on how to improve this: you could initialise newValue to array[0] and then run your loop from i=1 to avoid the if/else. And given you've already split the string on spaces your regex could just be `/./g` couldn't it? I think you need to concatenate some spaces back into the output string too.

Comment: The use of `continue` is not necessary here.